# Django how to access a uploaded file in views?

Tags: django, web

In my views.py file, there are some functions like follows:

```
def upload_file(request):
    """
    upload a file and store it into the database,
    and the file will be predicted in another view immediately.
    """

def predict(request):
    """
    make prediction of the file uploaded in the 'upload_file' function.
    """
```

How to access the file which uploaded in upload_file function in the predict function? Here is my thought:
1. read the last row in the database, but this sounds a little silly.
2. use a cache system and retrieve the file from cache?

Is there any useful solution for this problem? please give me any hints or other resources.

Thanks for anyone's help.

Comment: These are different views? So they get called independently of each other, right? In that case you need a reference (`pk`) to the image uploaded to be passed into the `predict` view (i.e. via the URL or the request parameters)

Answer (score 0):

As it is described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/files/#using-files-in-models), you can acces the storage url as Follows :

```
Class MyModel(models.Model):
       photo = models.ImageField()

   model = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1) #          for instance

  model.photo.url
  >>> 'https://media.example.com/mymodels/example_image.jpg'
```